# Can 'He's kissed the Blarney stone' be used as a metaphor?

Tags: metaphors

If someone has the gift of flattery, and is able to charm people with soft words, can one say, metaphorically, ***He's kissed the Blarney stone***?

Or does one literally have to have risked life and limb at Blarney castle to kiss the stone, (as I have), to be said to have ***kissed the Blarney Stone***?

Comment: I am Irish of descent, but having never invested in the literal challenge, I find no reason to force a literal accomplishment on the expression. "He's kissed the Blarney stone", as it were, by inheriting the gift of gab from some other source.

Comment: Why wouldn't anyone be able to use the expression metaphorically?

Comment: @Josh61 I'm sure people used to say, in dismissal of some sales talk *Oh, he's kissed the Blarney stone'. But I haven't heard it for a long time.

Comment: I think it's a racing certainty [this written instance](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22you+have+kissed+the+Blarney+stone+haven%27t+you%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) is entirely "metaphoric": *“You have kissed the blarney stone, haven't you, Johnny Yigal, but it's only Mama lnterlichia's lasagna talking, and that great white wine.”*

Comment: @WS2 - so what you want to know is if and how much the metaphor is still used. I guess!!

Comment: Ngram shows little but constant usage of this expression through recent decades. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=kissed+the+Blarney+Stone&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ckissed%20the%20Blarney%20Stone%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Josh61 But that graph shows some quite remarkable up and downs doesn't it. I wonder why the expression would have been 9 times as popular in the late 1930s as it was in the late 40s? And by the sixties it is back almost to the 1930s levels. Of course I suppose this includes both metaphorical and actual use. My impression is that it is not used metaphorically any more, but of course impressions are deceptive.

Comment: @WS2 - the up and downs are within a limited range anyway, so they are not very meaningful. I agree that it's usage Is quite rare.

Comment: @Josh61 and a fairly different pattern if you look at [AmE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=kissed+the+Blarney+Stone&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ckissed%20the%20Blarney%20Stone%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @Josh61 Why do you say 'within a limited range'? The percentage figures on the y axis are telling me that there were 9 times as many incidences of its use as in the late 1940s.

Comment: @WS2 - I mean that the range is between 0.000000100% and
0.000000400% , that is a limited number of hits anyway.

Comment: Check the rule book. You can't say it unless you've done. Lucky bastard.

Comment: Worse yet, you can't in truth be said to have "jumped the shark" unless, like the Fonz, you've actually jumped a shark.

Comment: Or "screwed the pooch".

Comment: Is this a phenomenon of "Hong Kong chow mein", where people in Hong Kong swear there is no such thing as "Hong Kong chow mein", but just various types of "chow mein"?

Comment: @BlessedGeek - I'm going to pretend you didn't say that. Mainly because I haven't the slightest idea what you're talking about.  :)

Comment: When someone tells me "I'm going to pretend you didn't say that", there is a high likelihood that I've said something offensive and I'm yet to be aware of it.

Comment: @BlessedGeek - That can be the case, but not in this instance. I really *didn't* understand your reference.

Answer (score 3):

Though I am not a native speaker I will risk this, brother (albeit with no risk to life and limb): if the [official website](http://www.blarneycastle.ie/pages/kiss-the-blarney-stone)'s claim, "*for over 200 years, world statesmen, literary giants, and legends of the silver screen have joined the millions of pilgrims climbing the steps to kiss the Blarney Stone and gain the gift of eloquence*", is true then I do not see why not using "He's kissed the Blarney stone" as a metaphor? It's rather very eloquent and beautiful.